shopify graphql is there a way to authenticate/login as a user/staff in a similar way to the customer token create mutation for customers?
I have a shopify plus store, I've created an admin app with read_users permission enabled then, on a separate system, I use graphql (called via php) to fetch companies, orders and customers associated with a specific staff member. I have no problem in fetching the data pertaining to a specific staff member, my problem is that before accessing this dashboard with the data, I'd like the staff member to fill in a login form with email and password and, if shopify confirms that it's indeed a real user, then the user logs in and can access the dashboard.
So basically, on my custom system:

the user is presented with a login form where he can fill in shopify email and password
my code should authenticate this user via shopify api
if shopify login is successful, then user can enter his custom dashboard
otherwise the user stays on the login page

My problem is that I don't seem to find anything related to user authentication in shopify docs. The best thing I found is the customerAccessTokenCreate mutation to fetch a customer token. I need something similar but for staff member instead of customer. Is there such a thing?
